# Firebase Authentication - How do I structure my react native app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-navigation

hope you are all safe.

My app currently uses this way of navigating between screen using React Navigation 5.0:

Firstly, it does this when authentication state changes:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true })
            } else {
                this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false })
            }
        })
```

And then, if the user is logged in then it will display the AppStack, else it will display AuthStack, which is the login and register screen.

```
render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                {this.state.loading ? (<LoadingScreen />) : this.state.isLoggedIn ? (<AppStack />) : (<AuthStack />)}
            </NavigationContainer>
        )
    }
function AuthStack() {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="LoginReg" component={LoginScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        </Stack.Navigator>)
}

function AppStack() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
                    if (route.name === 'Order') {
                        return (
                            <IconWithBadge
                                name={focused ? 'ios-book' : 'ios-book'}
                                size={size}
                                color={color}
                            />
                        );
                    } else if (route.name === 'Map') {
                        return (
                            <Ionicons
                                name={focused ? 'md-globe' : 'md-globe'}
                                size={size}
                                color={color}
                            />
                        );
                    } else if (route.name === 'Profile') {
                        return (
                            <Ionicons
                                name={focused ? 'md-contact' : 'md-contact'}
                                size={size}
                                color={color}
                            />
                        )
                    } else if (route.name === 'Notifications') {
                        return (
                            <Ionicons
                                name={focused ? 'ios-notifications-outline' : 'ios-notifications-outline'}
                                size={size}
                                color={color}
                            />
                        )
                    }
                },
            })}
            tabBarOptions={{
                activeTintColor: 'orange',
                inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
            }}>
            <Tab.Screen name="Order" component={OrderScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Map" component={MapScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
        </Tab.Navigator>)
}
```

Now, when the user registers, firebase authenticates the user and logs him in automatically. So the register screen unmounts before I manage to send some data to Firestore regarding the users date of birth etc.

I checked many many articles and docs online and I still don't know what's the most efficient way of handling this case, in order that I can also run some code before the register screen unmounts.

Am I doing this correctly in general or am I completely wrong? Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what causes the register screen to unmount?

Comment: firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true })
            } else {
                this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false })
            }
        })

This causes to set the isLoggedIn state to be set to true, and then it mounts the AppStack as you can see from my code in the post

Comment: that isn't causing an unmount. that's just updating the state of `isLoggedIn`. somewhere else must be causing the unmount?

Comment: my guess is that your state of `isLoggedIn` changes the view?

Comment: In the render function, you can see how I have `this.state.isLoggedIn ? (<AppStack />) : (<AuthStack />)`

Comment: Yes, `isLoggedIn` affects what will be rendered by changing the view

Comment: added an answer, let me know if makes sense and can talk about it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do is `setState` *after* doing async call

so you need to make an async request (can show a loading screen in the meantime) then once finished, you set the state to the new view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have the Register screen and Login screen in different .js files. How can I do that?

Comment: It's okay there in different files. good way to separate them out. where do you make the call to firebase with the DoB data?

Comment: In the register.js screen I send the data to firestore. Basically when the user clicks "Register" button I validate data and then I call the register function which in that firstly the user is created with email and password (a firebase function) and then (using `.then((res) => {...}`)  I send the data to firestore.

Comment: ok so why dont you `setState` in the `{...}` above? you could pass down a function that sets the state from the parent component and only do after the function has completed

Comment: You mean pass a function as a parameter to the AuthStack?

Comment: yeh pass a function to authstack that updates the parent components state after the request has finished to then render the new view you want

Comment: Okay I will try that then, thanks. It does seem a bit hacky workaround though. Do you have any idea of how I could do this differently, or is this considered a good practise? I am willing to change anything or everything ahaha

Comment: it's not hacky, it's the correct way to do it if you are using react with lifting state up and passing down functions to set state above. you could always use redux or another state management framework to control this for you if you're state gets out of hand

Comment: Okay, I'll try the function way and then maybe check out Redux. I really appreciate the help :) Thank you once again and have a nice day!

Comment: no worries. mark the answer as correct if it helped :) you can always ask another one if you get stuck on something else and I'd be happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

You could just have a second property in your state, something like `userDataSent`, which also needs to be `true` in order to display the `AppStack`.

Then you only set `userDataSent`, once you know you've sent the data/received it on your server.

You can store`userDataSent` as `true` or something in AsyncStorage and retrieve it when the app loads from cold, and update your state automatically each time.

Probably the simplest way to adapt what you've got!

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer :) Thing is that I have my login and register screen in different .js files. How could I achieve that then? Moreover, would you think of my way as a relatively efficient way or are there other significantly better ways of handling this register, login and app views?

Comment: What's your concern about them being in different files? Neither file needs to know about `isLoggedIn` or `userDataSent`. The parent component is deciding whether or not to show them. This is how it currently works in your code, you just need to add a second condition to display AppStack, i.e. `this.state.isLoggedIn && this.state.userDataSent`. As for efficiency, I haven't used React Navigation myself, so I'm not an expert... My only question would be how sure you are that you always want this behaviour (i.e. unmounting AppStack as opposed to displaying an error message or something).

Comment: There's no concern about them being in different files. But `userDataSent` variable will be in the register screen, since it's where the Register function is and will only set it to true within the Register.js file, and Register.js is the child component. Can parent component read child component variables? Also, I am not at all sure haha. I am also new to React Navigation

Comment: Ah I see. So you need to put the state in the parent component. Then you create a function in the parent as well to change it, something like `onRegister = () => this.setState({userDataSent: true})`. Then you pass that function down to the Register child component as a prop, like `onRegister={this.onRegister}`, then you can call it in the Register component just like `this.props.onRegister()`. Simples :)

Comment: Thank you very much, very appreciated. Now it makes sense! :)